# The Ruby Way exercise stuck (I18n)

Tags: ruby

Im reading The Ruby Way 3-rd edition. There is a simple example of I18n script in page 155, but when I run it with "ruby survay.rb" command it gives me an error

```
/home/name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:164:in `load_file': can not load translations from locale/en.yml~, the file type yml~ is not known (I18n::UnknownFileType)
```

I have latest ruby and rails. And I use Lubuntu.

source code /survay.rb

```
require 'i18n'
I18n.load_path = Dir["locale/*"]
I18n.enforce_available_locales = true
I18n.locale = ENV["LANG"].split("_").first || :en   

puts I18n.t("ask.name")
name = gets.chomp
puts I18n.t("ask.location")
place = gets.chomp
puts I18n.t("ask.children")
childnum = gets.chomp.to_i
puts I18n.t("ask.thanks")

puts name, place, childnum
```

source code /locale/en.yml

```
en: 
    ask:
        name: "What is your name?"
        location: "Where do you live?"
        children: "How many children do you have?"
        thanks: "Thank you!"
```

Comment: You wrote `source code /locale/en.rb`. shouldn't be `/locale/en.yml`?

Comment: Wow sorry, typo. There is .yml of course.

Comment: Is there a temp file there created by your text editor that is being picked up by `Dir["locale/*"]`?  `locale/en.yml~` kind of looks like a temp file.

Comment: Exactly, next thing I thought was that

Comment: You right. ls -A shows a temp files en.yml~

Comment: How can I rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
I18n.load_path = Dir["locale/*.yml"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `/locale/en.yml` instead of `/locale/en.rb`

Comment: It was a typo in this post.

Comment: Ic, so did you manage to solve the issue, or it is still giving you an error?

Comment: No, but it seams that it was a temp file en.yml~

Answer (score 1):

So the `yml~` refers to a temp file.

One thing you could do, is to make sure you have exited your editor before you run the script.

Otherwise you could do something like this in your code:

```
Dir["locale/*"].reject { |file| file.end_in?("~") }
```